# Question about R, How can take the mean of each category?

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I am trying to write a code to count how many times each category is named and then take the mean of each category.
How would I go about this? A for loop? a if else ? a function?

So I want to write a code that counts every time I can see ''Location''. It stores and then tells me there is 4 within this category. Also I want to take the mean. so 4 divided by 25 = .16

```
"location"    "Masculinity" "ownership"   "Masculinity" "difference" 
"agency"      "agency"      "Feminality"  "ownership"   "Feminality" 
"ownership"   "location"    "agency"      "Masculinity" "difference" 
"location"    "Feminality"  "ownership"   "agency"      "Masculinity"
"difference"  "difference"  "Feminality"  "location"    "Masculinity"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the expected output from the above input Do you need `mean(table(v1))`

Comment: The question is about counting the frequencies of categories. Then take the mean of what? You will get *one* value per category, the count. I am not seeing how computation of means apply here.

Comment: It may be that the OP wanted to loop over the rows and get the mean of the categories at the end.  Not clear though

Comment: maybe he want the mean of the whole vector

Comment: @akrun . Hm I guess what I want to do is.... write a code that counts every time I can see''Location''. It stores and then tells me there is 4 within this category. Also I want to take the mean. so 4 divided by 25 = .16

Comment: @Rose Please show your expected output in the post by `edit`ing so that others understand what you wanted.  thanks

Comment: @Rose -- See below code.  I believe it produces the result you described -- a table showing the frequency of the terms in your vector and their weight in the overall vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is also `split` the `vec` by the same object, get the `lengths` and divide by the `length` of the whole vector

```
lengths(split(vec, vec))/length(vec)
#   agency  difference  Feminality    location Masculinity   ownership 
#   0.16        0.16        0.16        0.16        0.20        0.16
```

---

Or with `count` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(vec) %>%
    count(vec) %>% 
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```

or use `adorn_percentages` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
tibble(vec) %>% 
    count(vec) %>%
    adorn_percentages("col")
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("location", "Masculinity", "ownership", "Masculinity", "difference", 
"agency", "agency", "Feminality", "ownership", "Feminality", 
"ownership", "location", "agency", "Masculinity", "difference", 
"location", "Feminality", "ownership", "agency", "Masculinity", 
"difference", "difference", "Feminality", "location", "Masculinity"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The table() command will produce a frequency table of the terms in your vector:

```
vec <- c("location",    "Masculinity", "ownership",   "Masculinity", "difference", 
         "agency",      "agency",      "Feminality",  "ownership",   "Feminality", 
         "ownership",   "location",    "agency",      "Masculinity", "difference", 
         "location",    "Feminality",  "ownership",   "agency",      "Masculinity",
         "difference",  "difference",  "Feminality",  "location",    "Masculinity")



 Frequency <- table(vec)
 Weight <- Frequency/length(vec)
 ans <- rbind(Frequency, Weight)
```